# ¿Cómo se aplica la encapsulación?

Tags: python, poo

Hoy practicando POO, encapsulación para ser exactos. En Python me di cuenta que si bien no puedes acceder al atributo encapsulado, sí se puede cambiar desde fuera de la función. Mí pregunta es, ¿esto es normal o es un error?

A esto es a lo que me refiero:

```py
class Alumno:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__secreto = 100


alumno1 = alumno()
alumno1.__secreto = "se puede cambiar"
print(alumno1.__secreto)
```

Esto mismo acaba imprimiendo "se puede cambiar" al  ejecutarse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tengo el mismo problema, y si bien soy bastante novato en el tema, me parece que la respuesta del compañero es errónea. Lo que pasa ahí, es que el programa está creando un nuevo atributo, realmente nunca se está detectando el primero.

Para comprobar esto, saca esto

```
alumno1.__secreto = "se puede cambiar"
```

y verás como Python te indica que no existe el atributo `__secreto`, es decir que `self.__secreto=100` no es leído por el interprete de Python.

Realmente no sé la solución a esto, y tampoco estoy 100% si lo que estoy diciendo es correcto o simplemente ignorancia en el tema, pero creería que lo que está ocurriendo es eso.

Comment: Se espera que des una respuesta, una indicación que solucione o explique el problema. Las opiniones sin fundamento no tienen valor. La respuesta FJSevilla es precisa, vuelve a leerla con atención.

Comment: muchas gracias!!! lo intentare

Comment: La respuesta de FJSevilla careció de algo que olvidó de aclarar, y hoy mismo otra persona me explicó. Lo que dije resulta ser cierto. Los atributos encapsulados dentro de una misma clase solo son accesibles, en la clase, no fuera de ella. Entonces, al crear vos una variable encapsulada en una clase, y después intentar "abrirla" o editarla fuera de esta, lo que haces es crear una nueva variable.

Comment: @CandidMoe este aporte si tiene valor, todos los aportes a la comunidad tiene valor. Lo que no tiene valor es la toxicidad en los comentarios de una respuesta.

Answer (score 6):

Hay que partir siempre de ésta premisa:

> En Python simple y llanamente, por diseño, **no existen los atributos y métodos privados** tal como los entendemos en lenguajes como C++. **Es imposible hacer un atributo o método realmente inaccesible** a alguien que sepa como funciona el lenguaje.

## Convención de estilo y "atributos/métodos privados"

Partiendo de la base de que no es posible hacer un método o atributo privado, es cierto que hay métodos o atributos que no deben ser accedidos directamente desde fuera de la clase ya que su modificación implica alterar de forma indebida el estado del objeto pudiendo dejarlo inservible incluso.

En Python, por convención, éstos métodos o atributos se denotan usando un simple subrayado delante del nombre:

```
class Foo:

    def _metodo_privado(self):
        self._atributo_privado = "Hola"
```

Para el lenguaje no significa absolutamente nada, para cualquier programador que se tope con ello si debe significar algo:

> Soy un atributo/método privado, no debes acceder a mi directamente a riesgo de que algo te explote en las manos. Si aún así no aprecias tus manos o tienes muy claro lo que estás haciendo, haz lo que te de la gana.

## El name mangling

En tu caso, usas un doble subrayado inicial para marcar como "privado" un atributo. Pero la primera sentencia de la respuesta es ley, dicha sintaxis no hace un atributo privado, eso es simplemente imposible.

En éste caso, para el lenguaje si tiene un significado, automáticamente el atributo se renombra a:

```
_<class_name>__<atribute_name>
```

la idea de ésto no es hacer privado nada, es evitar principalmente  colisiones de nombres accidentales y sobrescrituras de métodos de las superclases no buscadas durante la herencia.

Si esa es la intención, su uso es correcto, si se pretende hacer un atributo/método "privado" tal como se entiende en otros lenguajes, aparte de inútil, no está pensado ni es adecuado usarla para ello.

Hay un malentendido histórico importante con el name mangling asociado a la idea de atributo privado debido a la pequeña ofuscación que lleva a cabo para desempeñar su función, que básicamente es renombrar el atributo. Usar éste mecanismo para lo que no esa pensado es complicar las cosas para nada, por ejemplo complica la depuración del código.

Cuando se viene de otros lenguajes es normal no terminar de comprender ésto, incluso pensar que es una locura y que la implementación de Python de la POO es...
Es realmente una decisión de diseño y va acorde a la filosofía de Python y a su zen, no se suele intentar tratar al desarrollador como un "idiota" que no sabe lo que hace y por tanto hay que prohibirle que toque cosas que no debe por su propio bien. Los dos mecanismos mencionados sirven de aviso y para evitar errores accidentales, pero si se quiere acceder a un atributo o método el lenguaje te deja, se supone que sabes lo que haces si has llegado hasta ahí...

Hay quien se empeña en hacer posible lo imposible y pone todas las trabas que puede y más para evitar que se pueda acceder a un atributo o método, empezando por el mal usado name mangling, pasando por sobrescribir `__getattribute__` y todo lo que se nos pueda ocurrir, al final, si alguien quiere puede.

> En mi opinión, poner trabas artificiales para intentar hacer un atributo/método inaccesible es complicarse la vida uno mismo y al resto de desarrolladores que terminen con ese código en sus manos.

Por mucho que nos empeñemos, por mucho que sobrescribamos `__getattribute__` o hagamos lo que hagamos, al final siempre queda al menos una manera, nos quedará `object.__getattribute__` y no hay forma de impedir ésto dado que no hay objeto que no derive de `object` en Python:

```
class Alumno:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__secreto = 100
        

alumno = Alumno()
print(object.__getattribute__(alumno, "_Alumno__secreto"))
```

## La encapsulación en Python

El concepto de encapsulación en Python no es tanto hacer algo inaccesible, sino hacer que algo funcione sin que se vea su implementación interna, sin que el usuario sea consciente de los detalles de implementación internos. Un ejemplo son las propiedades, que pueden usarse para éste fin a la vez que actuar como el remplazo natural a setters y getters en otros lenguajes:

```
from typing import Union,  Optional


U_NUM = Union[int, float]

class Punto:
    def __init__(self, x: U_NUM, y: U_NUM) -> None:
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        
    @property
    def x(self) -> U_NUM:
        return self._x
        
    @property
    def y(self) -> U_NUM:
        return self._y

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.x}, {self.y})'


class Recta:
    def __init__(self, punto_a: Punto, punto_b: Punto) -> None:
        self._a = punto_a
        self._b = punto_b
        
        dx = self._b.x - self._a.x
        dy = self._b.y - self._a.y
        self._pendiente = (dy / dx) if dx else None
        self._origen = self._a.y - self.pendiente * self._a.x if dx else None
    
    @property
    def pendiente(self) -> Optional[float]:
        return self._pendiente

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({repr(self._a)}, {repr(self._b)})'
```

> ```
> >>> a = Punto(1, 3)
> >>> b = Punto(4, 7)
> >>> recta = Recta(a, b)
>
> >>> recta
> Recta(Punto(1, 3), Punto(4, 7))
> >>> recta.pendiente
> 1.3333333333333333
> >>> recta.pendiente = 7
> Traceback (innermost last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> AttributeError: can't set attribute
>
> >>> a
> Punto(1, 3)
> >>> a.x
> 1
> >>> a.x = 7
> Traceback (innermost last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> AttributeError: can't set attribute
> ```

No obstante, Python promueve el acceso directo a los atributos sin setters ni getters. Cuando se requiere que el acceso o reasignación al atributo leve aparejada la ejecución de cierta lógica (por ejemplo validación) se deben usar propiedades con la idea de mantener el "principio de acceso uniforme" acuñado por Bertrand Meye.

---

Después de todo lo dicho, realmente no estás cambiando el atributo, si fuera así el mencionado name mangling no estaría funcionando:

```
class Alumno():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__secreto = 100
        
    def print_secreto(self):
        print(self.__secreto)
```

> ```
> >>> alumno = Alumno()
> >>> alumno.__secreto = "se puede cambiar"
> >>> alumno.print_secreto()
> 100
> >>> alumno.__secreto
> 'se puede cambiar'
> ```

> ```
> >>> dir(alumno)
> ['_Alumno__secreto', '__class__', '__delattr__', ... '__secreto',  '__weakref__', 'print_secreto']
> # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                   ^^^^^^^^^^ 
> # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

El name mangling se establece solo en tiempo de definición, es en ese momento cuando el intérprete al generar el bytecode para la clase y crear el objeto en memoria traduce el nombre del atributo o método.

Lo que haces con:

```
alumno.__secreto = "se puede cambiar"
```

no es modificar el atributo, es crear uno nuevo. Precisamente ésta es la función del name mangling, evitar sobrescritura y solapamientos indeseados. De hecho:

```
alumno = Alumno()
print(alumno.__secreto)
```

> ```
> Excepción "unhandled AttributeError"
>  'Alumno' object has no attribute '__secreto'
> ```

Pero como se ha dicho por activa y por pasiva, ésto no hace al atributo inaccesible:

> ```
> >>> alumno = Alumno()
> >>> print(alumno._Alumno__secreto)
> 100
> >>> alumno._Alumno__secreto = "se puede modificar"
> >>> print(alumno._Alumno__secreto)
> se puede modificar
> >>> alumno.print_secreto()
> se puede modificar
> ```

---

### Edición

Para aclarar la duda planteada [en la respuesta de Joaquín Cerutti](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/380613/15089), dado que menciona mi respuesta (que puede que no fuera en verdad totalmente clara en este aspecto), aunque sea años después...

> ```
> alumno1.__secreto = "se puede cambiar"
> ```
>
> y verás como Python te indica que no existe el atributo `__secreto`, es
> decir que `self.__secreto=100` no es leído por el interprete de Python.

El interprete si que lee el atributo, lo crea y le asigna el valor, lo que cambia es que en vez de nombrar el atributo `__secreto`, lo nombra como `_Alumno__secreto`, solo hay que imprimir el contenido de `__dict__` de la instancia para verlo:

```
class Alumno:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__secreto = 100

alumno = Alumno()

print(alumno.__dict__)
# {'_Alumno__secreto': 100}
```

efectivamente cuando se intenta hacer:

```
alumno1.__secreto = "se puede cambiar"
```

obviamente te va a decir que el atributo no existe, es de suponer dado que la intención del *name mangling* es precisamente esa, evitar que ese atributo sea usado o sobreescrito de forma inadvertida posteriormente y para ello se le cambia el nombre. Pero podemos seguir accediendo al si queremos simplemente con:

```
>>> alumno._Alumno__secreto
100
```

y asignarle un nuevo valor también:

```
>>> alumno._Alumno__secreto = "se puede cambiar"
>>> alumno._Alumno__secreto
'se puede cambiar'
```

como que muy privado no es... y es que no se pretende que sea. Su función es evitar accesos o sobreescrituras no intencionadas (como colisiones de nombres en subclases) no poner un candado al atributo. El atributo "encapsulado" usando *name mangling* es accesible desde la clase y desde fuera de ella si de verdad queremos acceder a el, no es un atributo privado al estilo de Java por poner un ejemplo, ni pretende serlo e intentar forzar este paradigma en Python es hacer el código menos legible, mas complejo e inútil en ultima instancia.

Comment: Simplemente perfecto, no me has resolvido una duda sino que ademas me has dejado mas claro aun de como funciona el lenguaje. Muchas gracias!!!