# Problema con propiedades en python3 (funciona en una implementación, y en la otra no)

Tags: python-3.x

Pasa que llevo horas en un programa, y de la nada note un error demasiado extraño.
Entonces tras horas y horas de buscar, llegue a estas dos clases que hacen lo mismo pero no dan lo mismo (lo esperado mas bien)

No se si de la horas que llevo no veo que es, pero me parece raro esto que esta pasando.

¿Saben que puedo estar haciendo mal?

PDTA: Mi implementación también debería devolver 8

Muchas gracias.

```
class Quick_Tasks():

    def __init__(self,name=None):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        if type(value).__name__ == "int":
            self.__value = 8
        else:
            print("nel")


obj = Quick_Tasks("Arroz")
print("")
print(obj.name)
obj.name = 45
print(obj.name)

#########################################################

class TreeNode(object):
    """
    El error es que no pueod usar property con parametros. Debe ser asignacion manual. (ignorar)
    """
    def __init__(self, value = None):
        self.value = value
        self._left_node = None
        self._right_node = None

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.__value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        if type(value).__name__ == "int":
            self.__value = 8
        else:
            print("nel")

def main():
    tree_node = TreeNode(3)
    #tree_node.value = 3
    print (tree_node.value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("")
    main()
```

> Arroz
>
> 45
>
> 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu property se llama `name` pero asignas a un atributo `self.__value` en el setter:

```
self.__value = 8
```

ésto hace que `self.__name` nunca llegue a existir siquiera.

No obstante, dos observaciones:

- Generalmente se debe evitar el uso de `type` para validar tipos, si es necesario validar [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) es mejor opción. Tiene en cuenta las posibles clases derivadas (la herencia), de forma que validará también subclases directas o indirectas de la clase:

  > ```
  > >>> class Foo:
  > ...     pass
  > ... 
  > >>> class Bar(Foo):
  > ...     pass
  > ... 
  > >>> isinstance(Bar(), Foo)
  > True
  > >>> type(Bar()).__name__ == "Foo"
  > False
  > ```

  y generalmente se quiere dar soporte a la herencias. Además permite comprobar varios tipos en una misma llamada de forma simple:

  > ```
  > >>> isinstance(4, (int, float))
  > ```
- Si tus setters no van a lanzar una xcepción si el valor no es válido, lo correcto es declarar también los atributos "privados" en el inicilizador o te puedes encontrar con ésto:

  > ```
  > >>> inst = Quick_Tasks({})
  > >>> inst.name
  > Traceback (innermost last):
  >   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  >   File "main.py", line 11, in name
  >     return self._name
  > AttributeError: 'Quick_Tasks' object has no attribute '_QuickTasks__name'
  > ```
- Ten en cuenta siempre que no existen los atributos verdaderamente privados en Python y ten claro lo que `__nombre` hace realmente para no llevarte sorpresas:

  - [¿Cómo se aplica la encapsulación?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/361399/15089)

---

```
class QuickTasks:

    def __init__(self, name=None, value=None):
        self._name = None
        self._value = None
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            self._name = value
        else:
            print("nel")

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            self._value = value
        else:
            print("nel")
```

Aunque lo normal suele ser lanzar una excepción:

```
class QuickTasks:

    def __init__(self, name=None, value=None):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise TypeError("name must be str")
        self._name = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError("value must be int")
        self._value = value
```

La primera versión deja los atributos con el valor anterior si se intenta asignar un valor con un tipo no válido (`None` si se pasa un valor no válido al propio inicializador al instanciar). La segunda lanza inmediatamente una excepción, terminando con la ejecución del proceso si no es manejada.

Comment: muchas gracias por la aclaración.. Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto, osea obj = QuickTasks(4, '5'). No me arroja los errores que me debería arrojar. ¿por que?

Comment: Perdón un despiste, tenía un tipo al copiar y pegar el código, en el último setter tenía `@name.setter` también, corregido...

Comment: sip, exactamente eso cambie. pero cuando lo ejecuto. No me actúan los setter. Es decir, meto un str donde debe ir un int y lo vale :/