# NameError: name '_Coche__chequeo_interno' is not defined

Tags: python, poo, clase

Soy nuevo programando en Python y en el momento de ejecutar el programa, ocurre un erro, anexo codigo:

```
class Coche():

    def __init__(_self):
        _self.largoChasis=250
        _self.anchoChasis=120
        _self.__ruedas=4                                  # 2 guiones bajos, para que no se modifique desde afuera de la clase
        _self.enMarcha=False


    def arrancar(_self, arrancamos):
        _self.enMarcha=arrancamos

        if (_self.enMarcha):
            chequeo=__chequeo_interno()

        if (_self.enMarcha and chequeo):
            return "El Coche esta en Marcha"
        elif (_self.enMarcha and chequeo==False):
            return "Algo esta mal. No podemos arrancar"
        else:
            return "El Coche esta parado"


    def estado(_self):

        print("Largo del chasis: ", _self.largoChasis, " Ancho del Chasis: ", _self.anchoChasis, "Cantidad de ruedas: ", _self.__ruedas)


    def __chequeo_interno(self):

        print("Realizando chequeo interno")

        self.gasolina="OK"
        self.aceite="OK"
        self.puertas="Cerradas"

        if (self.gasolina=="OK" and self.aceite=="OK" and self.puertas=="Cerradas"):
            return True
        else:
            return False


miCoche=Coche()                                          # esto es lo que se llama instanciar una clase

print(miCoche.arrancar(True))

miCoche.estado()

print("----------- A continuacion creamos el 2do objeto -----------------------")

miCoche2=Coche()                                         # pertenece a la misma clase     

print(miCoche2.arrancar(False))

miCoche2.estado()
```

Comment: `__chequeo_interno()` es un método de instancia, se debe llamar a través de la referencia a la instancia que en tu caso la provee `_self`, es decir: `chequeo=_self.__chequeo_interno()`, no `chequeo=__chequeo_interno()`. Por cierto, ¿por qué usas `_self` y no `self`? Es un argumento que se pasa de forma automática, no tiene sentido marcarlo como "privado" y dificulta la legibilidad. En Python no existen los métodos o atributos privados, tenlo siempre presente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/361399/c%c3%b3mo-se-aplica-la-encapsulaci%c3%b3n/361411#361411

Comment: Puedes adjuntar el error que te da?

Comment: Gracias por los consejos, me funciono